# Using CopyArtifact to copy from a specific build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to copy artifacts from a specific build which is not always the latest. I'm searching for a way to copy the artifacts from a specfic build number.

Does anybody know if it is possible and how i can do that?

I use the following snippet in my pipeline script to copy the latest artifacts:

```
step ([
        $class: 'CopyArtifact',
        projectName: "myproject",
        filter: '_build/*.zip'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look in the [tests](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/hudson/plugins/copyartifact/CopyArtifactWorkflowTest.java) of the plugin, there is an example of how to configure a specific selector. If I try to extract it, it would look like:

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', 
      projectName: "myproject",
      filter: '_build/*.zip'
      selector: 
            [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', 
             buildNumber: "123"]
     ])
```

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple selectors? For example, besides the SpecificBuildSelector I'd like to include the StatusBuildSelector.

Comment: Not sure, I suppose you could download the repo and experioment with some unit tests

Comment: Add as separate question in SO?